# Automatically Log-In To Office 365

Tags: office365

My manager asked me to do research if the situation below is doable:

1. A student log in to a web portal provided by his university.
2. After logging in successfully, the student can use different web applications like Blackboard Learn, Office 365 etc.
3. If the student choose to use Office 365, the student will automatically be logged into Office 365 without typing username and passwords (currently, we provide a link to Office 365 log in page, then the students have to manually type in their username and passwords to log in).

In short, my question is that is it possible to log in to Office 365 from a web page (ASPX, PHP, HTML etc...) without the users typing the log in credentials manually?

The goal is to provide single sign-on support to the students so that they do not have to do multiple log in.

*I am aware of `ADFS`, but I am not sure if `ADFS` can make my situation as described above doable.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported, Based on OAUTH 2.0 the system needs to pass the credentials to the provider and get an access token that is used to for all subsequent calls from your app to o365 api. Hope this helps.